# Conditional Operator With Preg_Replace PHP

Tags: javascript, php, regex

I am currently trying to write a **Preg_Replace** in PHP, and make the "replacement" param a Conditional (Ternary Operator). Problem is, I can not get this to work. I am converting a BBCode Parser over to PHP from Javascript, and it is not going as planned.

Here is an example of what I am trying to do. This regex would work perfectly in JS, and from what I understand is this one will also work in PHP. I think it is running into the issues on the "replacement" param. I do not know how to get the Ternary Operator to work there. Any ideas? Here is an example piece of the code:

```
$string = "[b]This Matches, and Replaces[/b]";
$string = preg_replace("/(\[code\][\s\S]*?\[\/code\])|\[b\]([\s\S]*?)\[\/b\]/i", "$1 ? $1 : '<b>' + $2 + '</b>'", $string);
```

Simply my question is, how can I implement a Conditional Operator into a Preg_Replace that uses Match Groups from the Regex. Please help! :) Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php), below is an example:

```
$str = preg_replace_callback('~(\[code].*?\[/code])|\[b](.*?)\[/b]~si',
     function($m) { 
        return isset($m[2]) ? "<b>$m[2]</b>" : $m[1];
      }, $str);
```

Comment: Sorry took so long to reply, I have been busy! :) It works PERFECTLY, thank you!